# Why are my strawberries shaped like this?

Tags: fruits, strawberries

[image]

I moved my strawberries into my greenhouse earlier this spring for the first time and im aware that they are likely underpollinated (ill probably move them outside next year). I was wondering why they had grown in this shape and if the would still ripen. All the other underpollinated flowers have just died or the fruit not got bigger but on one plant they have all become this shape and keep getting bigger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strawberry fruit shown in your image shows clear signs of mutation - this could be caused by phytoplasma infection, see here https://www.rhs.org.uk/disease/phytoplasmas-of-berry-fruit or may just be phyllody, see here https://www.rhs.org.uk/problems/phyllody. Either way, you should remove and dispose of that particular plant because it will now only produce mutated fruits like this. There were likely symptoms on the flowers, but without seeing them, hard to say. Phytoplasma infection is not uncommon on berry fruits - there is no treatment once it occurs. If your other strawberry plants aren't doing well or start producing symptoms, you should dispose of those too I'm afraid.